# How to build a release version in CLion, c++ project

Tags: c++, clion

I have the following CMake file that CLion picked up automatically and created a run-debug profile for:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(shadowgate)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

include_directories(I:/onedrive/SDL2/include libs)
link_directories(I:/onedrive/SDL2/lib/x64 libs)

#lua54.dll needs to be copied to windows/system32 folder
add_library(Lua STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(Lua PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "I:/onedrive/lua4/liblua54.a"
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "I:/onedrive/lua4/include"
        )


file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/imgui/*.cpp)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}  ${SRC_FILES} )

#looks for a file with .lib extension
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} SDL2main SDL2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer Lua)

#AssetManager
add_custom_target(copy_assets
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/assets ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/assets
        )
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} copy_assets)
```

I don't see any options in CLion to copy this debug profile to a 'release' profile. I tried moving the executable to a seperate folder and add the needed .dll files next to it, but then it's still not finding the dlls.

How can I make a proper release of this project, where it will look for the .dll files in it's own directory?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the documentation first? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profile.html#add-profile

Comment: @Zaffy thanks that was what I'm looking for..doing a test now to see if there are no dll errors anymore

Comment: Everything works, if you want some points you can add it as an official answer @Zaffy